# redirecting git command output to another

Tags: linux, git, redirect

How can I redirect the command of a git command in "front" of another git command ?

for exemple how could I make the following command work proprely :

```
git diff --name-only | git commit -m
```

in the same way that I can redirect a ls to a cat -e

```
ls | cat -e
```

Thanks you!

Comment: Have you tries to add files before committing? So: git diff --name-only | git add && git commit -m ?

Comment: @davidmpaz yes I did it's not working.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. I was expecting that you could try variations of the given command in order to learn on the way. The solution is posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is this:

```
git diff --name-only | git add . && git commit -m"$(git diff --cached --name-status)"
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I want the "[message]"  to be replace by the output of gif diff --name-only ..

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can call git diff --cached at commit time, it will give you what was changed and added to the git stash.

Comment: Thanks you ! @davidmpaz

Comment: If this is what you were looking for, please can you accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks! Happy it did help you ;)